# $\hbar$ in Schrödinger's equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, physical-constants

We all know Schrödinger's equation
$$\mathrm{i}\hbar \partial_t |\Psi\rangle = H|\Psi\rangle$$
I'm trying to figure out why we multiply by $\hbar$ instead of e.g. $h$. What is causing us to specifically use $\hbar$? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we consider, e.g., the stationary solutions:
$$
H|\psi_n\rangle = E_n|\psi_n\rangle,\\
|\Psi_n(t)\rangle = e^{-\frac{iE_n t}{\hbar}}|\psi_n\rangle,
$$
we see that the time phase is:
$$
\frac{E_n t}{\hbar} = \omega_n t,
$$
which is consistent with the DeBroglie relation
$$
E=\hbar\omega=2\pi \hbar\nu
$$

In other words, if we expect the oscillations with frequency $\nu$, they will appear in a complex exponent with an additional factor of $2\pi$:
$$e^{i2\pi \nu t}=e^{i\omega t}
$$